# Retrieving Selected Row/Cell Values in DataGridView From one form to another

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new to C#.net . I want to get the dataGridView cell click cell values to textbox of another form but couldn't found the right method. I have two forms 1. UserPanelfrm and 2. frmAddProjects . UserPanelFrm consists of dataGridView which shows the list of projects from database . I want to show the cell information of the doubled clicked cell to be shown in textboxes of frmAddProjects.

Codes for ProjectClass.cs

```
public class ProjectClass
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DataConnectionClass.DbConnection);
    public int ManageProject(int ProjectID, String BusinessName, String ContactPerson, String Phone, String Address, String CreatedDate, String AssignedTo, String Mode)
    {
        try
        {
            int result = 0;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ManageProject", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ProjectID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessName", BusinessName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPerson", ContactPerson);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", CreatedDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssignedTo", AssignedTo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mode", Mode);
            conn.Open();
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

         }
    public DataTable SelectAllProjects()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ID,ProjectID,BusinessName,ContactPerson,Phone,Address,CreatedDate,AssignedTo from tbl_ProjectInformation", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(dr);
            conn.Close();
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Code to call ProjectList to UserPanelfrm dgvProjectDetails:

```
ProjectClass pc = new ProjectClass();
dgvProjectDetails.DataSource = pc.SelectAllProjects();
```

Code for cellclick

```
    private void dgvProjectDetails_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

DataGridViewCell cell = null;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell selectedCell in dgvProjectDetails.SelectedCells)
        {
            cell = selectedCell;
            break;
        }
        if (cell != null)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
            frmAddProjects.projectid = row.Cells["ProjectID"].Value.ToString();
            frmAddProjects.businessname = row.Cells["BusinessName"].Value.ToString();
            frmAddProjects.contactperson = row.Cells["ContactPerson"].Value.ToString();
            frmAddProjects.phone = row.Cells["Phone"].Value.ToString();
            frmAddProjects.address = row.Cells["Address"].Value.ToString();
            frmAddProjects.createddate = row.Cells["CreatedDate"].Value.ToString();
            frmAddProjects.assignedto= row.Cells["AssignedTo"].Value.ToString();
            // etc.
            frmAddProjects ProjectDetail = new frmAddProjects();
            ProjectDetail.ShowDialog();
        }
}
```

frmAddProjects code:

```
public static string projectid, businessname,contactperson,phone,address,createddate,assignedto;
     public frmAddProjects()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

public void fillRecord()
    {
        txtProjectID.Text = projectid;
        txtBusinessName.Text = businessname;
        txtContactPerson.Text = contactperson;
        txtPhone.Text = phone;
        txtAddress.Text = address;
        dTPCreatedDate.Text = createddate;
        cmbAssignedTo.Text = assignedto;
    }
```

Comment: i searched in various forums but couldn't get the right step. I followed http://dotnetaid.com/retrieving-selected-rowcell-values-in-datagridview-from-c-net-winform/ but didn't helped.

Comment: I put an answer to what I think you are asking, but your question could be improved. For example, you should show where your fillRecord is being called, and also show how you declare the fields/properties in frmAddPRojects. Also, you don't explained exactly what is the problem that you are having, as in what kind of result you have when you try your code, exceptions, etc.

Comment: One more thing... What you are asking in the title of the question and what you are asking in the text of the question are different things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show, in a TextBox in another form, the content of a cell in a GridDataView after a DOUBLE click, first, you have to use the CellMouseDoubleClick event.

A suggestion:

```
    private void dgvProjectDetails_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int col = e.ColumnIndex;
        int row = e.RowIndex;

        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        if (dgv == null)
            return;

        var cell = dgv[col, row];

        if (cell != null)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
            frmAddProjects ProjectDetail = new frmAddProjects(); //<= THIS must be created first

            ProjectDetail.projectid = row.Cells["ProjectID"].Value.ToString();
            ProjectDetail.businessname = row.Cells["BusinessName"].Value.ToString();
            ProjectDetail.contactperson = row.Cells["ContactPerson"].Value.ToString();
            ProjectDetail.phone = row.Cells["Phone"].Value.ToString();
            ProjectDetail.address = row.Cells["Address"].Value.ToString();
            ProjectDetail.createddate = row.Cells["CreatedDate"].Value.ToString();
            ProjectDetail.assignedto= row.Cells["AssignedTo"].Value.ToString();
            // etc.

            ProjectDetail.ShowDialog();
        }            
    }
```

I'm assuming that all those fields in the frmAddProjects are public. By your code, they seems to be "static", that would be the only way to set them before instantiating an object of this type, but I did as if they where just public properties.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The fields are public. I used your code but it didn't showed another form on doubleclick and used the codes in private void dgvProjectDetails_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) but it only showed the form but couldn't retrieve the data to textboxes. Please help.

Comment: If the ProjectDetail form is not being showed, it is because ((DataGridView)sender)[col, row] is returning null... Ups!!! My mistake. It is a DataGridViellCell object. I'll change in the code.

Comment: @krishnawlsol, with the little changes, it should work now. :)
This code will not work on data grid cell change event because the "event is different". A double click on a cell is one thing, change the content of a cell is another thing

Comment: Hello Jauch, Thank you for your help. It solved the issue. Below is the solution as you suggested. I forgot to call fillRecords. ProjectDetail.Show();ProjectDetail.fillRecord();

Comment: @krishnawlsol, if I was of help, please, consider accepting my answer as the correct one and upvoting it :)

Comment: @krishnawlsol, I would consider putting the call to fillRecord on the Show event of the form, for example, instead of calling it after Show(). Also, Show() is different from ShowDialog(). The last one will wait the form to close before return.

Comment: i am low in reputation sorry i couldn't vote up but you've been a great help. Thank you for your help.